# Pigeon-Hole Probability principle

Tags: probability, pigeonhole-principle

I am trying to solve the following question:

Consider a list of randomly generated lowercase $3$-letter "words" printed on a paper. The letters cannot be repeated.

So, then I deduced that there must be $$\begin{pmatrix}26 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}25 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}24 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$ unique words.

However, if I want to figure out how many words must be printed in order to have at least $3$ identical "words" on the list, I am not exactly sure what that means. How can you have identical words? In which case, wouldn't that be extra counting in the original computation of the number of $3$ letter words to begin with?

Comment: multiplication might be better than addition

Comment: As an example your list of words might have *cab* three times

Comment: But then aren't you adding a word twice in there? Because why would you get "cat" twice? Isn't that redundant, especially when the order matters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first off the sentence "The letters cannot be repeated" must mean that within a single word no repetition is allowed. This gives you
$$
3!\binom{26}{3}=6\times2600=15600
$$
unique words to begin with. Then if you print more than $2\cdot 15600$ words, then by the Pigeon Hole Principle, at least one of the words must be repeated three times in the list, so the answer is that when
$$
2\cdot15600+1=31201
$$
words are printed at least one of the words is repeated three times.

Comment: @Henry: Right! Order matters

Comment: How come the order doesn't matter? What I did was P(26,3). Your solution suggests that the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @Christian: Yes, you are absolutely correct. I forgot to actually think.

Comment: Oh that makes more sense. So they're not looking for identical words within the subset of possible words, but how many times would they have to print it rather, to ensure the words are duplicated. Thank you!